# SQL query to get records inserted over last 7 days grouped by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table two very similar tables that store `purchases` and `downloads` they both look similar to this with an id and date

```
id  date                          

1   2020-06-15 18:25:27.415548+01
2   2020-06-15 11:03:30.157502+01
3   2020-06-15 17:09:15.592209+01
4   2020-06-14 18:29:18.332623+01
5   2020-06-13 18:09:31.990473+01
... many more rows ...
```

I would like to be able execute a Postgres query that returns the count of all the purchases and downloads inserted over the last 7 days grouped by day. An ideal response would look like this

```
date          purchase_count    download_count

2020-06-13    37                64
2020-06-14    44                56
2020-06-15    34                63
2020-06-16    41                72
2020-06-17    30                40
2020-06-18    42                55
2020-06-19    9                 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation with `full join`:

```
select dte, coalesce(d.downloads, 00) as downloads, coalesce(p.purchases, 0) as purchases
from (select date_trunc('day', date) as dte, count(*) as downloads
      from downloads
      group by dte
     ) d full join
     (select date_trunc('day', date) as dte, count(*) as purchases
      from purchases
      group by dte
     ) p
     using (dte)
order by dte;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. How would I get it to return `0` instead of `NULL` if there are no records for a given day?

Comment: @malimichael . . . Using `coalesce()`.  I updated the answer.